# Direct image of a vector bundle under birational morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a birational map of smooth projective varieties over complex numbers. Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$. Will $f_*E$ be a reflexive sheaf. Is it possible to impose some additional conditions to ensure that the direct image is a reflexive sheaf?

Comment: you can take double  dual  $(f_∗E)^{**} $.

Comment: @Hassan Jolany Sorry I don't understand your comment. Can you elaborate? Even $(f_*E)^*$ will be reflexive right?. But I am interested to know when $f_*E$ itself is reflexive

Comment: read this paper of Hartshorne http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002320002

Comment: In general, Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper dominant morphism of normal integral schemes and $f$ be equidimensional. If $F$ be a coherent reflexive sheaf on $X$ then $f_*F$ is a coherent reflexive sheaf on $Y$.

Comment: Take for $f$ the simplest example of birational morphism, the blowing up of a point $p$ in a surface; let $E$ be the exceptional divisor. Then $f_*\mathcal{O}(-E)$ is the ideal sheaf of $p$, which is not reflexive.

Comment: @ abx - I think your comment is so elegant you really ought to consider making it an answer so that people searching this will see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested I put my comment into an answer: take for $f$ the simplest example of birational morphism, the blowing up of a point $p$ in a surface; let $E$ be the exceptional divisor. Then $f_*\mathcal{O}(-E)$ is the ideal sheaf of $p$, hence is not reflexive.